# Why doesn't Visual Studio launch my website?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

My physical website was having issues, so I pulled up the old project in Visual Studio 2015.

First, it wouldn't compile because my plugin was outdated. We didn't really use that image resizing tool much anyway, so I removed the old references.

Now when I launch it, I get nothing.

There are breakpoints in the Global.asax.cs page for `Application_Start`, `Session_Start`, `Application_BegineRequest`, `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, `Application_Error`, `Session_End`, and `Application_End`. Nothing is being hit.

I rebooted my PC. It still won't launch the website.

The page comes up with the little favicon showing on the tab of the blank page, but there is nothing on it. Just an empty page.

Page source is empty also.

There is a warning inserted into the Event Viewer whenever I launch Visual Studio, but I'm not sure what to make of it:

> The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\jp2code\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

What can I look into?

[image: screenshot]

Jamshaid Kamran got me past that part, now I have another odd error: Visual Studio says that the library file that is included as another Project of the Solution is not there, but in the code window there are no errors there and it compiles - it just errors whenever the page tries to run.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: error-screen]

And here is a screenshot of my code with the missing DLL above highlighted:

[image: code-screen]

Comment: First, in the solution directory, check for a hidden folder `.vs`. Just delete it. Then,  `Clean and Rebuild` the solution

Comment: @JamshaidKamran, that got me past that and to another error that I updated the question with. Visual Studio compiles the code just fine, but whenever it launches the website it says that it cannot find one of the DLL files.

Comment: Well, if it is complaining, then you might need to restart the visual studio and see if does it again or not.